# Using PHP SimpleXML to access non-default namespace element attributes

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I have some annoying XML from an API response that looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><report><QueryResult>
  <ResumptionToken>123456</ResumptionToken>
  <IsFinished>true</IsFinished>
  <ResultXml>
    <rowset xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:rowset">
      <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:saw-sql="urn:saw-sql" targetNamespace="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:rowset">
        <xsd:complexType name="Row">
          <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="Column0" saw-sql:aggregationRule="none" saw-sql:aggregationType="nonAgg" saw-sql:columnHeading="0" saw-sql:displayFormula="0" saw-sql:length="4" saw-sql:precision="12" saw-sql:scale="0" saw-sql:tableHeading="" saw-sql:type="integer" type="xsd:int"/>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Column1" saw-sql:aggregationRule="none" saw-sql:aggregationType="nonAgg" saw-sql:columnHeading="ISBN" saw-sql:displayFormula=""Bibliographic Details"."ISBN"" saw-sql:length="255" saw-sql:precision="255" saw-sql:scale="0" saw-sql:tableHeading="Bibliographic Details" saw-sql:type="varchar" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Column2" saw-sql:aggregationRule="none" saw-sql:aggregationType="nonAgg" saw-sql:columnHeading="ISSN" saw-sql:displayFormula=""Bibliographic Details"."ISSN"" saw-sql:length="255" saw-sql:precision="255" saw-sql:scale="0" saw-sql:tableHeading="Bibliographic Details" saw-sql:type="varchar" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Column3" saw-sql:aggregationRule="none" saw-sql:aggregationType="nonAgg" saw-sql:columnHeading="Publication Date" saw-sql:displayFormula=""Bibliographic Details"."Publication Date"" saw-sql:length="255" saw-sql:precision="255" saw-sql:scale="0" saw-sql:tableHeading="Bibliographic Details" saw-sql:type="varchar" type="xsd:string"/>
          </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:schema>
      <Row>
        <Column0>0</Column0>
        <Column1>55555555 444444445</Column1>
        <Column3>[2019]</Column3>

      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Column0>0</Column0>
        <Column1>555555555</Column1>
        <Column3>©2009.</Column3>
      </Row>
```

I'm using PHP's SimpleXML to parse this data, but am struggling to access the column headers located in the non-default namespace under xsd:element. For example, I need to access the value: saw-sql:columnHeading="Publication Date", as this column can be dynamic and isn't always "Publication Date". So I'm looking to pluck out the values for saw-sql[@columnHeading].

I've tried all manners of registering the namespaces with Xpath, using attributes() etc etc. The closest I got was:

```
$ResponseXml->registerXPathNamespace('xsd','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema');
$elements = $ResponseXml->xpath('//xsd:element[@minOccurs]');
```

This actually got me the default namespace attributes, but I need the ones for saw-sql, and the same method of:

```
$ResponseXml->registerXPathNamespace('saw-sql','urn:saw-sql');
$elements = $ResponseXml->xpath('//saw-sql:element[@columnHeading]');
```

does not get me any results.

Comment: There seems to be some problems with your document as some fields have quotes in quotes - saw-sql:displayFormula.  If that is fixed perhaps use `xpath('//*[@saw-sql:columnHeading]')`

Comment: @NigelRen yeah his sample XML is not valid XML. for example `<resultXML>` is never closed.

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath `//saw-sql:element[@columnHeading]` is looking for elements named `element` (in the saw-sql namespace), which have attributes named `columnHeading` (in no namespace), but the element names are actually in the `xsd` namespace, while the attributes *are* in the `saw-sql` namespace.

So I believe what you want is:

```php
$ResponseXml->registerXPathNamespace('xsd','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema');
$ResponseXml->registerXPathNamespace('saw-sql','urn:saw-sql');
$elements = $ResponseXml->xpath('//xsd:element[@saw-sql:columnHeading]');
```

Comment: Also, it's _always_ a good idea to provide a well-formed XML document as your example, rather than a fragment. That's so that people who want to help can copy and paste the data and test it, rather than have to muck about fixing it up first, or hazard some kind of answer without actually testing it (which is liable to yield answers which also have mistakes)

Comment: Yes sorry this was a fragment and not closed out. This still only gets me the attributes in the XSD namespace (minOccurs etc) unfortunately. I can never seem to get anything from saw-sql.

Comment: What does the expression `//xsd:element[@saw-sql:columnHeading]` return you? An empty set?

Comment: There are lots of things wrong with your XML; not just that it's a fragment; even the part you have posted is syntactically not well-formed. Either you've corrupted it while pasting it into StackOverflow, in which case you will need to fix it to get more help from us, or if this is actually what your upstream API has returned you then you will need to either fix that API or else process its response using some non-XML tool, because that's not XML.

Answer (score 0):

fwiw you could use DOMDocument to parse it instead of SimpleXML, for example

```php
<?php

$xml = <<<'XML'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><report><QueryResult>
  <ResumptionToken>123456</ResumptionToken>
  <IsFinished>true</IsFinished>
  <ResultXml>
    <rowset xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:rowset">
      <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:saw-sql="urn:saw-sql" targetNamespace="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:rowset">
        <xsd:complexType name="Row">
          <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="Column0" saw-sql:aggregationRule="none" saw-sql:aggregationType="nonAgg" saw-sql:columnHeading="0" saw-sql:displayFormula="0" saw-sql:length="4" saw-sql:precision="12" saw-sql:scale="0" saw-sql:tableHeading="" saw-sql:type="integer" type="xsd:int"/>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Column1" saw-sql:aggregationRule="none" saw-sql:aggregationType="nonAgg" saw-sql:columnHeading="ISBN" saw-sql:displayFormula=""Bibliographic Details"."ISBN"" saw-sql:length="255" saw-sql:precision="255" saw-sql:scale="0" saw-sql:tableHeading="Bibliographic Details" saw-sql:type="varchar" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Column2" saw-sql:aggregationRule="none" saw-sql:aggregationType="nonAgg" saw-sql:columnHeading="ISSN" saw-sql:displayFormula=""Bibliographic Details"."ISSN"" saw-sql:length="255" saw-sql:precision="255" saw-sql:scale="0" saw-sql:tableHeading="Bibliographic Details" saw-sql:type="varchar" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Column3" saw-sql:aggregationRule="none" saw-sql:aggregationType="nonAgg" saw-sql:columnHeading="Publication Date" saw-sql:displayFormula=""Bibliographic Details"."Publication Date"" saw-sql:length="255" saw-sql:precision="255" saw-sql:scale="0" saw-sql:tableHeading="Bibliographic Details" saw-sql:type="varchar" type="xsd:string"/>
          </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:schema>
      <Row>
        <Column0>0</Column0>
        <Column1>55555555 444444445</Column1>
        <Column3>[2019]</Column3>

      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Column0>0</Column0>
        <Column1>555555555</Column1>
        <Column3>©2009.</Column3>
      </Row>
XML;
$domd = new DOMDocument();
@$domd->loadHTML($xml);
foreach ($domd->getElementsByTagName(strtolower("ResultXml")) as $resultXml) {
    $keyNames1 = [];
    $keyNames2 = [];
    foreach ($resultXml->getElementsByTagName("rowset") as $rowset) {
        foreach ($rowset->getElementsByTagName("sequence") as $sequence) {
            foreach ($sequence->getElementsByTagName("element") as $element) {
                $keyNames1[] = $element->getAttribute("name");
                $keyNames2[] = $element->getAttribute(strtolower("saw-sql:columnHeading"));
            }
        }
    }
    $rows = [];
    foreach ($resultXml->getElementsByTagName("row") as $row) {
        $rowData = [];
        foreach ($keyNames1 as $keyName1Key => $keyName1Name) {
            $tmp = $row->getElementsByTagName(strtolower($keyName1Name));
            if ($tmp->length) {
                $rowData[$keyNames2[$keyName1Key]] = $tmp->item(0)->textContent;
            }
        }
        $rows[] = $rowData;
    }
    var_export($rows);
}
```

yields

```php
array (
  0 =>
  array (
    0 => '0',
    'ISBN' => '55555555 444444445',
    'Publication Date' => '[2019]',
  ),
  1 =>
  array (
    0 => '0',
    'ISBN' => '555555555',
    'Publication Date' => '©2009.',
  ),
)
```

- i used loadHTML instead of loadXML because DOMDocument insists that your XML is not valid XML; in loadHTML() mode, everything is lowercase for some reason, in loadXML() everything is case-sensitive.

Comment: HTML is case insensitive and does not support namespaces. So the XML gets modified if you treat it as HTML.

Answer (score 0):

`SimpleXMLElement::attributes()` allows you to access the attributes of a specific namespace providing the namespace URI as a parameter.

```php
$value = $simpleXMLElement->attributes($namespaceURI);
```

But first I would suggest defining a constant (or variable) for the namespaces that you are using. This will make your code a lot more readable and avoid typos.

Be aware that "rowset" redefines the default namespace for itself and the descendant element nodes, they are not in the "empty/none" namespace.

```php
// define a dictionary for the namespaces
const XMLNS = [
    // same alias as in the document
    'xsd' => 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema',
    // let's use a shorter alias
    'saw' => 'urn:saw-sql',
    // own alias - used without alias in the document
    'rowset' => 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:rowset'
];

$report = new SimpleXMLElement(getXMLString());
foreach (XMLNS as $alias => $uri) {
    $report->registerXpathNamespace($alias, $uri);
}

$columns = [];
foreach($report->xpath('//xsd:complexType[@name="Row"]/xsd:sequence/xsd:element') as $element) {
    $columns[] = [
        // read the attribute (fallback to '' if missing), cast to string
        'name'=> (string)($element['name'] ?? ''),
        // read attribute with namespace
        'heading'=> (string)($element->attributes(XMLNS['saw'])['columnHeading'] ?? '')
    ];
}

var_dump($columns);
```

Output:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(7) "Column0"
    ["heading"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(7) "Column1"
    ["heading"]=>
    string(4) "ISBN"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(7) "Column2"
    ["heading"]=>
    string(4) "ISSN"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(7) "Column3"
    ["heading"]=>
    string(16) "Publication Date"
  }
}
```

#### The Xpath Expression

- Fetch the type definitions: `//xsd:complexType`
- Filter for "Row": `//xsd:complexType[@name="Row"]`
- The elements inside the sequence:
  `//xsd:complexType[@name="Row"]/xsd:sequence/xsd:element`

The part in `[]` are conditions for nodes returned the previous location path. So `//foo[@bar]` would return the `foo` element nodes with a `bar` attribute, while `//foo/@bar` would return the `bar` attributes of all `foo` element nodes.

#### DOM

This solution would not look much different with DOM. The Xpath processor is a separate object and here are specific methods to work with namespaces (suffix "NS"). DOM is more specific and powerful then SimpleXML.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML(getXMLString());
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
foreach (XMLNS as $alias => $uri) {
    $xpath->registerNamespace($alias, $uri);
}

$columns = [];
foreach($xpath->evaluate('//xsd:complexType[@name="Row"]/xsd:sequence/xsd:element') as $element) {
    $columns[] = [
        'name'=> $element->getAttribute('name'),
        'heading'=> $element->getAttributeNS(XMLNS['saw'], 'columnHeading')
    ];
} 

var_dump($columns);
```